# Compare lines in 2 text files

Tags: python, csv

I have two large text files (200,000+ lines), CSV format. I need to compare them, line by line, but the fields maybe switched within each line.

Example file `A.csv`:

```
AAA,BBB,,DDD  
EEE,,GGG,HHH  
III,JJJ,KKK,LLL
```

Example file `B.csv`:

```
AAA,,BBB,DDD  
EEE,,GGG,HHH  
LLL,KKK,JJJ,III
```

So for my purposes, `A.csv` and `B.csv` should be "identical" even though fields are switch in the first and last line. Since the fields in each file might be in a different order, the usual options like grep or diff won't work.

Basically, I think I need to write something that reads a line of `A.csv` and `B.csv`, and checks if all fields are present in both lines, independent of the order. Alternatively, something that orders the fields after reading the lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can normalize the check, without affecting the data.

```
with open('big1.csv') as i, open('big2.csv') as j:
   a = csv.reader(i)
   b = csv.reader(j)
   for linea in a:
      lineb = next(b)
      if sorted(map(str.lower, linea)) != sorted(map(str.lower, lineb)):
          print('{} does not match {}'.format(linea, lineb))
```

Comment: You can replace lines 4 and 5 with `for linea, lineb in zip(a, b):`

Comment: You can, but this would load all the file in memory and the question is specifically asking for large files.

Comment: Even if `zip()` creates an iterator?

Comment: @fenceop Only on Python 3.x; and since its not tagged specifically - the solution with manual iteration will work in both versions.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid...One question and forgive lack of knowledge here...but does reading a line in a csv file skips the emtpy fields, like in `AAA,BBB,,DDD` ? so the linea will be `['aaa','bbb',ddd']`?

Comment: No - you'll get `['AAA','BBB','','DDD']` for `'AAA,BBB,,DDD'`. If you want to ignore blanks in your comparison, you'll have to filter them out.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Tested on minimal example files, works like a treat!  Thank you!

Comment: @BurhanKhalid How can I filter out the empty fields?

Answer (score -1):

Try using `diff` as a Linux/Unix command line - this is very useful for comparing files.