# Counting list elements using `set`

Tags: python, python-2.7

In an older post ([Python: count repeated elements in the list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240969/python-count-repeated-elements-in-the-list)), I noticed two replies (answer 3 and 5) that use `set` to count repeated elements of a list.

In a question I asked myself recently ([Compare lines in 2 text files with different number of columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34753845/compare-lines-in-2-text-files-with-different-number-of-columns)), it was mentioned that a `set` only contains unique elements; the python documentation says the same (https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html).

How does something like this work, if `set` is supposed to contain unique elements only:

```
yourList = ["a", "b", "a", "c", "c", "a", "c"]
duplicateFrequencies = {}
for i in set(yourList):
    duplicateFrequencies[i] = yourList.count(i)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those solutions are only creating `set`s so that they only count the occurrence of each element a single time. For something like `[1, 2, 1]`, a naive counter would count the `1`s and find a pair of them, then count the `2`s and find one of them, then count the `1`s *a second time* (not too useful). Since a `set` only includes unique elements, this duplication of counting is eliminated. A `set` out of that `list` would be `{1, 2}`, so `1`'s occurrences in the original `list` are counted only once and `2`'s occurrences in the original `list` are counted only once.

Answer (score 1):

We call count on the original list, not the computed set.